# How to find hidden files with Python?

Tags: python

How to find hidden files with Python?
This is my code
I think the code is very wrong
Thanks for the better solutions

```
import os,ctypes,sys
from pathlib import Path as path
d='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz'
drive=['%s:\\' %i.upper() for i in d if os.path.exists('%s:' %i)]

def walk(pa):
    def findhide(path):
            for c in os.listdir(path):
                try:
                    new=path/c
                    print(c)
                    if os.path.isdir(new):
                        find(new)
                #find hiden file
                        
                except PermissionError:
                    continue
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    sys.exit()
            
        p=path(p)
        find(p)
```

Comment: You're reimplementing the very useful `os.walk` method here.  You should just use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm using the bitwise and (`&`) correctly but the following seems to work on my Windows machine:

```
>>> import os
>>> import stat
>>> path = 'sa.txt'
>>> fa = os.stat(path).st_file_attributes
>>> bool(fa & stat.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
True
>>> path = 'sa.bat'
>>> fa = os.stat(path).st_file_attributes
>>> bool(fa & stat.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
False
>>>
```

Comment: voted up answer! most simplest!